# Why MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity call ExecutePendingTransactions manually?

Tags: performance, android-fragments, mvvmcross

Use mvvmcross for Xamarin.Android. Why MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity call ExecutePendingTransactions in ShowFragment method manually? What actions done with this call? As I see, it can takes about second for several devices while navigation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically necessary, if the next actions rely on the handling of the commit() before doing any other action.

For MVVMCross especially:

```
OnFragmentChanging(fragInfo, ft);
ft.Commit();
SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
OnFragmentChanged(fragInfo);
```

The OnFragmentChanged-Event should obviously only be called if the changes got applied. Just to take one of the code snippets out of `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`.

From the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29).

> After a `FragmentTransaction` is committed with
>   `FragmentTransaction.commit()`, it is scheduled to be executed
>   asynchronously on the process's main thread. If you want to
>   immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this
>   function (only from the main thread) to do so. Note that all callbacks
>   and other related behavior will be done from within this call, so be
>   careful about where this is called from.

Comment: Thanks, Cyriac. Could you please advise, how to improve navigation speed. Because now even not very complex fragment can opened about 2 seconds(for Nexus 4). What is the reason of it? maybe, reflection, when bindings from axml are created? If I change it to bindings from code, can it improve my speed?

Comment: Well using the latest MVVMCross Version is a good start, since they did some changes on the bindings (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1342). My application navigates in around a second to an activity, with a fragment with two other fragments inbetween and a tablayout in one fragment, while having a realtime-plotting-chart in the other fragment (All my bindings are done in the axml). So it probably depends on what are you doing during the navigation.

Comment: Ok. But in addition to this, I have issue with animation - ripple effect hangs as all navigation process is in main thread. Is it possible to do anythinh except adding delay before ShowViewModel?

Comment: I use Delay there aswell, though there should be the option to use a ProgressDialog, but i have no experience at this topic since this got minor priority for me at the moment.